# Ten old questions of mine have been downvoted within a span of 2 minutes.

Tags: bug, down-votes, serial-voting

I just noticed that my reputation score dropped significantly since my last time checking in. 
Upon further inspection I saw that on a number of older question I asked, someone downvoted my questions, one after the other. 
Why could this happen? Could it be a system glitch, a moderator review or perhaps even sabotage?

Comment: Another option is that someone might have taken offense to your meta question concerning supposed hidden symbolism in the math.SE logo and used serial downvoting as "retaliation".

Comment: @Arthur Of course the MSE logo has hidden symbolism: it's SE's way of ribbing us: we're not only a bunch of [squares,](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_%28slang%29) but one taken to higher dimensions, i.e. a bunch of cubes!   Joking aside, it would be nice if someone would devise a better logo.

Comment: @ArthurFischer I'm not sure who would retaliate; someone Jewish thinking I was making a conspiracy or someone who hates Jews thinking I'm a Jew trying to trump up my tribe? Clearly though, someone thought the question was out of line and wanted to make that known

Comment: @BillDubuque lol! I also think it is time soon for a more up-to-date logo.

Comment: Behold, my old questions continue to get downvoted for no apparent reason. Are there any mods who can find out what is going on?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you check your reputation history for today you'll find the following entry:

> +10 Serial downvoting reversed

There is an automatic script that reversed such anomalous vote patterns. Those votes you see were reversed and you regained the reputation you lost from the downvotes.

Answer (score 2):

It is none of those things. As far as I can tell, somebody downvoted seven of your questions because he thought that seven of your questions deserved downvotes.

Comment: I find it odd that someone decided to traverse old questions, many of which received upvotes, and start down-voting them.

Comment: I think this case is similar to [this one](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1720/downvoted-by-another-user-for-the-wrong-reasons/1724#1724)

Comment: Note that at least one of your questions was downvoted twice.

Comment: Five votes were cast with a delay of three seconds between each one. Legitimate downvoters usually take more time to evaluate a post than three seconds.

Comment: @MadScientist thank you, I'm not sure why Qiaochu wasn't able to pick up on that and actually thought someone was able to evaluate seven questions in ten seconds. Unless Qiaochu was the one who downvoted them.

Comment: @Imray Now you're getting into baseless speculation territory. And there were only five invalid votes, the other two were almost certainly from another user (else they would have been invalidated)

Comment: @MadScientist You're right. I'll let this go